# How to mass change password attributes in AIX uname -rv=3 5 for all users but root

Tags: users, aix

I want to do a mass change on all users but root in AIX for the following "password attributes":

```
Weeks before password reuse: 15
Password min length: 6
```

Can it be done, or do I need to do them one at a time? I tried to use the F6=Command button to see what it runs, but it appears to be running some sort of script and this is beyond me. Are there any other users (besides `root`) whose attributes I should leave unchanged?

Comment: Can you copy the script shown by F6 put a copy up on pastebin? Please make sure it contains no sensitive data. Maybe we can help put it in a loop for you. (my AIX box is at 3.2)

Answer (score 2):

There are other users besides root that are daemons (process managers) that you shouldn't change.

If all of your users are not in the same group, you could select by home directory (if they share common home). In the simplest case the following should work.

```
for user in $(grep "/home" /etc/passwd | cut -s -d':' -f1)
do
    chuser minage=15 minlen=6 $user
done
```

Always test sections of code, especially before applying a command modifying users ability to login, *you may have to undo your work in a hurry if you get it wrong*

Try the following first, to ensure you have a valid list of users you wish to alter

```
for user in $(grep "/home" /etc/passwd | cut -s -d':' -f1)
do
    echo $user
done
```

Try `chuser minage=15 minlen=6` on your username and `lsuser` on your username before applying the same command to other users.

Answer (score 0):

```
# lsuser -a minlen minage support
support minlen=8 minage=0

# chuser minage=1 minlen=6 support 

# lsuser -a minage minlen support 
support minage=1 minlen=6
```